Black screen or Delayed screen on 144hz
My laptop screen randomly started going black or VERY,VERY delayed when it’s anything above 60hz.
It started on 144hz, then 135, then 130,etc.
It also has Horizontal lines on top and only 2% of top of the screen is functional.
It’s also like this in BIOS settings.
I also don’t get an Asus splash screen when booting up.
It’s an Asus TUF15 laptop.
I tried to look everywhere, but I didn’t even find out whether it’s Hardware related or Software related.


Take it to a repair shop for a qualified diagnosis.

The fact it is progressing, and that it is impacting boot and BIOS screens, means it is a hardware problem.

Your computer has a hardware fault. You can tell this is the case because these symptoms are progressing (impacting more and more of the possible supported settings) and because they are impacting the pre-OS environment (BIOS/UEFI screens and boot images).
If it were a software issue, it would only impact while the software (the OS, presumably) is running. Because the computer is being impacted when the OS isn't running, it isn't a software issue.
You should pursue warranty service, or if your computer is out of warranty, speak with a competent local PC hardware technician.
